# Merge tags "indexes", "indices" with "indexing"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I think the tags [indexes](/questions/tagged/indexes) (333 questions) and [indices](/questions/tagged/indices) (66 questions) should be merged with [indexing](/questions/tagged/indexing) (2,584 questions). They could also be merged with [index](/questions/tagged/index) (2,484 questions), I think the other way is better.

This calls for some discussion weather [index](/questions/tagged/index) should be made a synonym for [indexing](/questions/tagged/indexing). I noted that 134 [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/index+indexing) has both tags "index" and "indexing". Is having both [index](/questions/tagged/index) and [indexing](/questions/tagged/indexing) motivated? I think no but I am not sure.

I also found another tag which is redundant. [full-text-indexing](/questions/tagged/full-text-indexing) (333 questions) is as I see it a synonym for [full-text-search](/questions/tagged/full-text-search) (2,330 questions). [The mysql documentation for "full-text-..."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) supports this as I see it. Hence I think [full-text-indexing](/questions/tagged/full-text-indexing) should be removed and made a synonym.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the [full-text*] part though. They talk about the same stuff more or less, but from a different perspective in my understanding (-indexing from the DBA point of view, -search from the application point of view). But I don't know much about any of that so...

Comment: @Mat I don't think Olof meant merge full-text tags with indexing tags, just reduce the number of full-text tags.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: " full-text-indexing ... is as I see it a synonym for full-text-search " - I understand this as merging/synonymyzyng these two tags, which I'm not a big fan of on the face of it. (But as I said, not my domain.) All in favor of squishing the various other index tags together though.

Comment: @Mat I'm in the SQL Server crowd and I think that merge is logical for both SQL Server and MySQL.